# How to Disable / Enable AuditTrail in zappdev using mamba

Tags: zappdev

I have a parser(mamba operation) and I need to disable the Audit Trail functionality on start of parser, and enable it again when it ends.

How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to show some code so that we can possibly help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can disabled it like this:

```
CommonLib.DataContext.ExecuteInUnitOfWork(obj => {
      //place your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it needs a return obj to work like below.

CommonLib.DataContext.ExecuteInUnitOfWork(obj => {
      //place your code here
      return obj ;
});

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method for disabling audit trail is the ExecuteWithoutAuditTrail.
Write something like this:

```
CommonLib.DataContext.ExecuteWithoutAuditTrail(manager => {
    //write your code here
    return manager;
});
```